# Openshift schedule deployment via ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible, cron, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I have multiple openshift application deployment configured to be deployed by ansible (triggered by Jenkins). Some of the applications need to be scaled down to cut costs.

Is it possible to adapt the deployment helm chart to scale down and scale up according to a schedule? Can openshift scheduler be used for this?

Would scaling up and down be equivalent to completely deleting the deployment and associated PV and charts?

Right now a Jenkins job is scheduled to delete and then recreate the deployment. But it makes every application to have the same downtime which is not the desired result. I do not want to write a Jenkinspipeline for each and every application.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: vini-test
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: partner-db
              image: some-image
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - date; echo $date > /tmp/cronjob.log
              - mkdir -p /tmp/openshift && cd /tmp/openshift && curl -L https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v3.11.0/openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit.tar.gz -o openshiftstuff.tar.gz && tar -xf openshiftstuff.tar.gz && mv openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit/oc /usr/bin -f && mv openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit/kubectl /usr/bin -f
              - oc get pods -n vini-test
              - oc scale deployment partner-db --replicas=0
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to adapt the deployment helm chart to scale down and scale up according to a schedule? Can openshift scheduler be used for this?

Helm is used to deploy applications, so I do not think you can use this to scale the application during runtime, but I might be wrong.

What you can always do is to deploy an additional `CronJob` that will use `oc scale` or a similar command to do the scaling on a regular basis. This can also be done in a single Jenkins Pipeline that will loop over the necessary projects dynamically and scale them down (maybe only do this for projects with a certain label?).

> Would scaling up and down be equivalent to completely deleting the deployment and associated PV and charts?

Scaling using `oc scale` / `kubectl scale` works by setting the `replicas` in the `Deployment` `spec` to another value, thus adding or removing Pods, not by deleting Deployments or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked examples of cronjob in openshift, but i couldnt find anything which runs some command to scale up and down. also the cron job are attached to pods. so when i scale down the pod is deleted and how can i scale it up if the cron job is created in the pod? or am i understanding the whole idea wrong? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/html/developer_guide/dev-guide-cron-jobs DOc i referred to

Comment: CronJobs just run certain Pods in a regular interval. In the CronJob, you'll need to run a container that contains the `oc` command line and then run the `oc scale` commands inside the Pod. Hope that helps.

Comment: I created a cronjob but it  creates a pod and terminates itself. But if i understood your statement right, inside that container i have to install oc and do a oc scale down/up as required

Comment: i have updated the question with the cronjob i m using to scale the deploment down. I m unable to see the logs from the pod. and the scale down has also not functioned

Comment: Ok. i updated the cron job and i got it working. With the official openshift/origin-cli image and giving permissions for the user to access the namespace